# javascript inside dhtmledit (vb6)

Tags: javascript, vb6, dhtml

I would like to use some javascript in a dhtmledit element in an vb6 application. How can I do this ?

I imagine I can include it within

```
<script>
</script>
```

but how do I get to run it when I want it ?

Thank you in advance